What is a good (second) introduction to affine geometry
Every discussion of affine geometry I have encountered is "peripheral".  It either assumes the reader has already learned the topic elsewhere, or that no deeper understanding is needed beyond what is discussed in the context.
Is there a good source on affine geometry which strikes a balance between abstraction and concrete motivating examples?

As I recall there is a discussion in
Coxeter, H. S. M., [Introduction to geometry. 2nd ed], New York etc.: John Wiley and Sons, Inc. XVI, 469 p. (1969). ZBL0181.48101.
